# Expected Value of the Square of Two Random Variables

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, expected-value

If we let X be a random variable with expected value **m** and variance **k**, and let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be random variables that result from applying $X$ to two independent trials of this particular Bernoulli experiment, what is $E((X_1 − X_2)^2)$?

I learned linearity of expectation, but as far as I have gotten was $E((X_1)^2-2*X_1*X_2+(X_2)^2)$ after polynomial expansion.

I've no clue how to proceed from here.

Comment: Hint: Use the _linearity of expectation_ and the fact that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, then $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate True, that makes sense. Am I suppose to express the *entire* answer in terms of *m* and *k* ?

Comment: @ViolettaBlejder yes, you've to express it in terms of m and k

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, we have $$\mathbb E[X_1X_2] =\mathbb E[X_1]\mathbb E[X_2] = \mathbf m^2.$$
(As an exercise, you might want to prove from the definition of independence that it indeed implies the expectation of the product is the product of the expectations - assuming both random variables have finite second moment.)
It follows then that
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[(X_1-X_2)^2] &= \mathbb E[X_1^2 -2X_1X_2 +X_2^2]\\
&= \mathbb E[X_1^2] - 2\mathbb E[X_1X_2] + \mathbb E[X_2^2]\\
&= 2(\mathbf m^2 +\mathbf k - \mathbf m^2)\\
&= 2\mathbf k.
\end{align}

Comment: Quick answer but unfortunately quite wrong.The correct answer is $2k$.

Comment: Oh, I see my error. I will correct it now.

Comment: @DilipSarwate In the answer above, is there a skipped step? I'm lost as to how it goes from like 2 to line 3 in the equation. I understand that E[X1X2]=E[X1]E[X2] = $m^2$, but the appearance of the *k* has me lost.

Comment: @ViolettaBlejder Recall that for any square-integrable random variable $X$,
$$
\mathsf{Var}(X) = \mathbb E[X^2] - \mathbb E[X]^2.
$$
Rearranging gives
$$
\mathbb E[X^2] = \mathbb E[X]^2 + \mathsf{Var}(X),
$$
which in this case is $\mathbf m^2+\mathbf k$.

Comment: @Math1000 Thus, for the second variable, it is also *m^2 + k*, and subtracting *2m^2* gives *2k*, that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I accidentally wrote $\mathbb E[X]$ instead of $\mathbb E[X]^2$ at first. Also note that this result holds for any i.i.d. pair of random variables with finite second moment; the actual distribution is irrelevant.